# How do I access inventory variables for a given host in my Ansible connection plugin?

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am developing a new Ansible collection to manage configuration of network devices. These devices are configured only over API. I need to be able to define them in an inventory file. From my understanding, I should create a new connection plugin and use it to connect to devices.

The problem starts when I try to access my connection plugin configuration options. These values are device-specific so it would be best to define them in an inventory file.

When I run a playbook that uses `config_module` I am getting an error:

```
fatal: [device_1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "No setting was provided for required configuration plugin_type: connection plugin: plugin_name setting: address "}
```

How do I access inventory variables for a given host in my connection plugin?

It seems to have been [possible](https://github.com/xlab-steampunk/ansible-pms-plugins/tree/master/connection) in Ansible 2.9

Inventory file:

```
all:
  children:
    site_a:
      hosts:
        device_1:
          ansible_connection: connection_name
          ansible_device_address: device_1_ip
          ansible_device_username: device_1_username
          ansible_device_password: device_1_password
```

Connection plugin:

```
DOCUMENTATION = """
---
author: ...
connection: connection_name
short_description: ...
description:
  - ...
version_added: 0.0.1
options:
  address:
    description:
      - ...
    required: true
    vars:
      - name: ansible_device_address
    type: string
  username:
    description:
      - ...
    required: false
    default: default_username
    vars:
      - name: ansible_device_username
    type: string
  password:
    description:
      - ...
    required: false
    default: default_password
    vars:
      - name: ansible_device_password
    type: string
"""

from ansible.plugins.connection import ConnectionBase
from ansible.plugins.loader import connection_loader

class Connection(ConnectionBase):
    transport = "connection_name"

    def __init__(self, play_context, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Connection, self).__init__(play_context, *args, **kwargs)
        self._local = connection_loader.get("local", play_context, "/dev/null")
        
        self.hostname = self.get_option("address") # this line crashes
        # if line above is commented out
        # lines below always return default value from documentation 
        # irrespective of what is defined in inventory file
        self.username = self.get_option("username") 
        self.password = self.get_option("password")
    
    ...
```

Configuration module (`config_module.py`):

```
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from ansible.module_utils.connection import Connection

def run_module():
    module_args = ...
    result = {"changed": False, "message": "", "changes": [], "debug": []}
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=module_args, supports_check_mode=True)
    conn = Connection(module._socket_path)
    ...

def main():
    run_module()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am running Ansible 8.2 [ansible-core 2.15.2]

I've noticed that my other calls to `self.get_option(option)` always return default value from connection plugin documentation irrespective of what is defined in the inventory file.

I've also tried (based on [Ansible plugin config & docs standards](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#plugin-configuration-documentation-standards)):

```
from ansible.plugins.connection import ConnectionBase
from ansible.plugins.loader import connection_loader

class Connection(ConnectionBase):
    transport = "connection_name"

    def __init__(self, play_context, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Connection, self).__init__(play_context, *args, **kwargs)
        self._local = connection_loader.get("local", play_context, "/dev/null")
        self.set_options()
        self.hostname = self._options["address"]
        self.username = self._options["username"]
        self.password = self._options["password"]
    
    ...
```

but I get the same error.

I could pass them from the playbook to `config_module` as arguments and define `ansible_connection: local` for each device in inventory but it:

- raises separation of concerns issue (module for configuration should not care about connection details)
- adds additional arguments for each task with `config_module` (there will be many in a playbook)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Ansible by design. As described [here](https://groups.google.com/u/2/g/ansible-devel/c/ow7Ipk6LEj4) this would be a bug and a security issue. Using HttpApi plugins is a correct approach for such use case.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced locally your case.

a) I created a connection plugin named "test" ( copy of ssh + adding one variable variable1 + filling of documentation section )
=> The test with first playbook and inventory.yml ( including specific value for variable1) is OK

**inventory.yml**

```
all:
  hosts:
    XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA:
      ansible_ssh_user: xxxxxxx
      ansible_ssh_pass: yyyyyyy
      variable1: "toto"
```

**play1.yml**

```
- name: test connection
  hosts: all
  connection: test
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Display variable1 
      debug:
        msg: "Variable1 = {{ variable1 }}"
```

output => ansible-playbook play1.yml   -i inventory.yml

```
PLAY [test connection] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Display variable1] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA] => {
    "msg": "Variable1 = toto"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

b) i created a simple module name "my_test"( based on ansible documentation : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html). I added several blocks to declare "variable1" and set variable1 from module parameters

=> the test with second playbook and inventory.yml ( including specific value for variable1) is OK

**extract of module code:**

```
...
def run_module():
    # define available arguments/parameters a user can pass to the module
    module_args = dict(
        name=dict(type='str', required=True),
        new=dict(type='bool', required=False, default=False),
        variable1=dict(type='str', required=False, default="tutututu")
    )
...
```

**play2.yml**

```
 name: test my new module
  hosts: all
  connection: test
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: debug variable1
    debug:
      msg: "{{ variable1 }}"
    when: variable is defined
  - name: run the new module with variable1 setted
    my_test:
      name: 'hello'
      new: true
      variable1: "{{ variable1 }}"
    register: testout1
    when: variable1 is defined
  - name: run the new module without variable1 setted
    my_test:
      name: 'hello2'
      new: true
    register: testout2
    when: variable1 is not defined
  - name: dump test output when variable1 is defined
    debug:
      msg: '{{ testout1 }}'
  - name: dump test output when variable1 is not defined
    debug:
      msg: '{{ testout2 }}'
```

output => ansible-playbook play2.yml   -i inventory.yml

```
PLAY [test my new module] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug variable1] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA]

TASK [run the new module with variable1 setted] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA]

TASK [run the new module without variable1 setted] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA]

TASK [dump test output when variable1 is defined] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
        },
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "message": "goodbye",
        "original_message": "hello",
        "variable1": "toto"
    }
}

TASK [dump test output when variable1 is not defined] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

3. I tested with modify entry in inventory with no variable1, and it's the default value from the module which is used : "tutututu"

output :

```
PLAY [test my new module] *******************************************************************************

TASK [debug variable1] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA]

TASK [run the new module with variable1 setted] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA]

TASK [run the new module without variable1 setted] *******************************************************************************
changed: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA]

TASK [dump test output when variable1 is defined] *******************************************************************************
ok: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
}

TASK [dump test output when variable1 is not defined] *******************************************************************************
ok: [XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
        },
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "message": "goodbye",
        "original_message": "hello2",
        "variable1": "tutututu"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing but I never had an issue accessing vars from a regular module. This question is specifically addressing connection plugins